# Is there a term for games that use kinetics?

Tags: terminology

Is there a particular name for categorizing board games that have some kinetics?
Some of the examples are Fireball Island (monster throwing fireballs), Monopoly Jackpot (push button spinner) etc.

Comment: Almost all games involve moving *something* around, which we could call "kinetics". Where are you drawing the line between those examples and games that involve rolling dice or moving pieces?

Comment: I *think* OP is referring to games in which fine motor skills are purposefully required as an integral part of game play, for example, striking objects by flicking components toward them ([Flick 'em Up!](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/169124/flick-em)). These would be called [Dexterity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_game#Categories) games.

However, Monopoly Jackpot, I would posit, isn't a Dexterity game, but rather just includes a spinner as a game component.

I don't believe there's a catch-all term that combines the concept of a true Dexterity game and spinners.

Comment: @Manath This certainly answers my question. Thank you so much!!

Comment: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/5552/finger-flicking-games is also relevant

Comment: @Manath Right, it's not a dexterity game because you're just meant to give the spinner a shove.